# How can I disable a service via Delphi?

Tags: delphi, service

I use a routine that can start and stop services via Delphi but I also need to be able to disable them, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', 'sc config "the service name" start=disabled', nil, SW_HIDE);
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', 'sc config "the service name" start=auto', nil, SW_HIDE);
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', 'sc config "the service name" start=demand', nil, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: That's poor man service management. sc.exe is designed to be used by command line or scripts - and it not available on older Windows versions - application should use the SCM API.
And if you'd really like to use SC, there's no need to invoke a shell. Run sc.exe directly.

Comment: I understand that's not que ideal solution but it worked as I needed for a specific problem. I'm evaluating the OpenService solution for general use.

Comment: Also consider that using the SCM API it's much easier to get errors, if any. Using a command line tool besides the exit code you may have to intercept and parse the output, which is more difficult and may be language-specific. For a quick-and-dirty solution it's ok, but I would not use it as a general solution. Also check the JCL, IIRC there are some classes to manage services.

Answer (score 19):

Open the service with [`OpenService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330.aspx), and then disable it by passing `Service_Disabled` as the `dwStartType` parameter for [`ChangeServiceConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987.aspx). Specify a null pointer or `Service_No_Change` for the rest of the parameters since you're not interested in changing them.

Comment: Also be aware the user must have proper rights to change service configurations.

Answer (score 8):

You can use file JclSvcCtrl.pas from JEDI Components Library (JCL).
I have written a pseudo example that you could use. However, be aware that I didn't test it. But in this way it should work (error checks omitted):

```
M := TJclSCManager.Create;
M.Refresh(true);  //Not sure if true is needed or not (refresh all services)
For i := 0 to M.ServiceCount -1 do
begin
  S := M.Services[i]; //TJclNtService
  if CompareText(S.ServiceName, 'bla') then
  begin
    S.Stop;
    S.StartType := sstDisabled;   
    S.Commit;
    break;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Of course you can also use M.FindService. It does exactly the same!

Comment: I'm a big fan of JEDI Library, I'm definitely use it.

Answer (score 7):

Besides using the previous methods, if you need more control you can use WMI.
With [Win32_Service class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-service) have access to all information of the services installed on the machine and you can has access to methods: Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, Interrogate, Create, Delete, Change, ChangeStartMode...

Here ([Web](https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/componentes-glibwmi/) / [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glibwmi/))you can find a set of components to work with WMI (**GLibWMI components Library**); There are one called **CServiceInfo** thah give you all information and some methods of this class.

In addition with the package tere are some demos; One is called (ServiceControl) and implement all methods.

[image]

All the package are source included. See the code it can be usefull for you.

Regards.

Comment: El proyecto tiene muy buena pinta Neftalí... Felicitaciones por la iniciativa!

Comment: Gracias Juan Antonio. La verdad es que aun está en la primera fase, pero tiene muchas posibilidades para ampliar funcionalidades. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

An other option is to use the [DelphiVault ServiceManager unit](https://github.com/carmas123/delphi-vault/blob/master/Source/DelphiVault.Windows.ServiceManager.pas) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917648/2306907)):

```
var 
    SM: TServiceManager;
    Svc: TServiceInfo;
begin
    SM := TServiceManager.Create;
    try
        SM.Active := True; 
        Svc := SM.ServiceByName['MyServiceName'];
        Svc.SetStartType(ssDisabled);
    finally
        SM.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Be aware that proper access rights are needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i use

> It's just a little wrapper around some
>   Windows API Functions we found useful
>   to handle NT-Services. It allows you
>   to query, start, stop, pause and
>   enable/disable NT-Services on the
>   local or a remote system.
>
> http://blog.marcduerst.com/post/How-to-use-TServiceManager-to-manage-Windows-services.aspx

Which lets you write 'nice' delphi code ;)

```
procedure DisableService(ServiceName: PChar);
var SM: TServiceManager;
begin
  SM:=TServiceManager.Create;
   try
     SM.Connect;
     SM.OpenServiceConnection(ServiceName);

   //not working with TServiceManager as is
   //but its easy to fix, see below        
    SM.DisableService;


   finally
    SM.Free;
   end;
end;
```

the DisableService section hasnt been written,  but all that is needed is

```
 procedure TServiceManager.DisableService;
 begin
   ChangeServiceConfig(ServiceHandle, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,SERVICE_DISABLED,SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil);
 end;
```

Comment: The Delphi code would be nicer if it demonstrated what Eder asked for instead of what he said he already knows how to do.

Comment: yes your right, i didn't read the question completely, i shall update it

Comment: What a pity, link is broken now

Comment: This is a link to the contect of the blog, but cannot seemtto find a download anywhere. http://www.idev.ch/content/how-use-tservicemanager-manage-windows-services

Comment: Aaand this is the exact reason why we don't like answers on SO which rely on links. Because those links break over time and the answer becomes useless.

Comment: Here is a version of the source code: https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1322.