# How to cause standard dialogue of properties of service?

Tags: delphi

(Example: start services.msc, click 2 times on any service)
If it is possible an example on delphi, please

Comment: I don't believe that there is an official programmatic way to do this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To reach that that has written - it is admissible there is a Form1, on it is Button1 and Edit1, after pressing Button1 should the window of properties of the service written in Edit1, for example W32Time

Answer (score 2):

David is probably right ;-) In any case, whatever you want to do with services programatically will probably involve the use of the Service Control Manager API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and here's another SO question that might help you further

[How can I disable a service via Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401528/how-can-i-disable-a-service-via-delphi)

and here's some old code that gives you a head start

http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1322

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
SCM Api to me it is known, using it it is possible to learn only the status of service or to stop-start service, but here to cause a standard window of properties of service which it is possible to see in services.msc - SCM cannot. And to draw it "in manual" it would not be desirable, besides, thus it is impossible to set passwords on an input and dependences.
Still ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no official programmatic way to show the services control panel UI to the user.

Consequently I believe that you must look for another solution.

Comment: Prompt then at least as in Delphi to read value of parametre <a service name> \DisplayName a kind "%SystemRoot %\system32\wevtsvc.dll,-200" (for WinXp full names there were written, and in Win7 here so). I suspect, what this reference but a line resource how it to get if Win7x64?

Comment: @user I can't understand that comment.

Comment: example: h:=loadlibrary('c:\windows\system32\w32time.dll'); result: h=0 (on win7x64)

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't know where you are going with all this. I already answered your question as far as I can. I honestly believe there is no answer, you can't get the service properties dialog to show through a Windows API call, unless I have missed something.